# Solve $x^2u_{xx}-u_{yy}= -2x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to solve the following initial value problem

> $x^2u_{xx}-u_{yy}= -2x, x>0, y>0$
> $u(x,y) = 0,\,\, u_y(x,y) = 0$ on $\Gamma:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\,x>0,\,y = 0\}$

With the substitution $\xi = y-\log(x)$, $\eta = y+\log(x)$. From here, I need to solve

> $-4u_{\xi\xi}-u_{\xi}-u_\eta = -2\exp\left(\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}\right)$

How can I proceed from this point? Is there some other approach for finding the exact solution to this problem?

Comment: I have not done the calculation, but the second equation does not look right to me. In any case, if your equation is correct, try separation of variables.

Comment: I agree with Deane, this doesn't look right. The original equation is hyperbolic, while your transformed equation is parabolic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2u_{xx}-u_{yy}= -2x$$
HINT :
$$u(x,y)=v(x,y)-2(x\ln(x)-x)$$
$$x^2v_{xx}-v_{yy}= 0$$
Now one can try the separation of variables : $\quad v(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$